# Ansible Docker Connection Error

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-registry

I am running ansible version 1.9, docker-py version 1.1.0 and Docker 1.9.1. I have a private insecured docker registry running at http://registry.myserver.com:5000.

I have an ansible task to start a container using a pulled image from this remote registry:

```
---
  - name: Start User Service Container
    docker:
        name: userService
        image: user-service
        registry: registry.myserver.com:5000
        state: running
        insecure_registry: yes
        expose:
          - 8355
```

However, this is currently returning the following error:

> failed: [bniapp1] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
>   msg: ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory')),)

Verbose output:

```
<54.229.16.155>
<54.229.16.155> image=discovery-service registry=http://registry.myserver.com:5000 name=discoveryService state=running
<54.229.16.155> IdentityFile=/home/nfrstrctrescd/bni-api.pem ConnectTimeout=10 PasswordAuthentication=no KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no User=centos ControlPath  =/home/nfrstrctrescd/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r PreferredAuthentications=g  ssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey ControlMaster=auto ControlPersis  t=60s
<54.229.16.155>
<54.229.16.155> IdentityFile=/home/nfrstrctrescd/bni-api.pem ConnectTimeout=10 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=hxhptjipltjnteknbbxkqgcdwvwshen  p] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-hxhptjipltjnteknbbxkqgc  dwvwshenp; LANG=C DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 LC_CTYPE=  C DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/opt/docker/certs /usr/bin/python /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/a  nsible-tmp-1460499148.45-268540710837667/docker; rm -rf /home/centos/.ansible/tm  p/ansible-tmp-1460499148.45-268540710837667/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"'' PasswordAuthe  ntication=no KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no User=centos ControlPath=/home/nfrst  rctrescd/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-m  ic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey ControlMaster=auto ControlPersist=60s
failed: [bniapp1] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
msg: ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory')),)
```

Note: When i run the container manually on the remote server, the image gets pulled and the container is started correctly:

```
docker run registry.myserver.com:5000/user-service
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my docker daemon was not running. Adding the following ansible code before starting docker fixed it for me:

```
# Start Docker Service
- name: Start Docker service
  service: name=docker state=started
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
- name: Boot Docker on startup
  service: name=docker enabled=yes
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
```

Comment: You can do a single call: `service: name=docker state=started enabled=yes`